# ASP.Net Identity Manual Password Hashing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, password-protection, asp.net-identity

I'm developing an **MVC 5** web application using **Entity Framework Database First** approach with an **existing database**.

I'm also using **ASP.Net Identity** for my Authorisation and Authentication, however, I'm not using the built in Entity Framework code, i.e., **UserManager**, **ApplicationUser** etc instead I'm using an approach similar to this by Brock Allen.

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

I'm now working on Account Login and Registration and I want to **hash the User password** before I store it in my custom User table.

I realise I can create my own custom class which implements **IPasswordHasher**, however, that's where I become stuck. Below shows a mock up of how I think it should work, however, I'm not entirely sure this is even correct.

```
public class CustomPassword : IPasswordHasher
{
    public string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        return password;
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        if (hashedPassword.Equals(providedPassword))
            return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
        else return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

These are my questions:

**Q1**:When registering a new user account and I pass the user password
    into the HashPassword method from my Account Controller, like this,
    I would like the User password hashed and returned as a string,
    however, I don't know what code to put into the **HashPassword**
    function to do this.

```
CustomPassword pwd = new CustomPassword();
String UserPassword = "test@123";
String HashedNewPassword = pwd.HashPassword(UserPassword);
```

**Q2**:When a User then logs into the website, I would like to take their supplied password, retrieve the hashed password from the database user table, and then compare them inside the **VerifyHashedPassword** method, but again, I don't know what the code is to compare a hashed string against a non-hashed string.

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a tool like dotpeek and take a look into the original code (which uses PBKDF2)

Comment: @tgriffiths you can have a look how Microsoft implemented it: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs

Answer (score 23):

After creating UserManager instance, assign the passwordhasher property to your CustomPasswordHasher

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
UserManager.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher(); // IPasswordHasher
```

Use the UserManager to find user with username and password.

Comment: UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(pass) , what I needed  for generate password as same as MVC5 mechanism.

Comment: Awesome answer, I went mad because my CustomerUserStorage was implementing both IPasswordHasher and IPasswordStore but the IPasswordHasher is a property of the store itself.